# Set and Clear Interval turns into multiple Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to develope a slider, which change every 5 seconds if the user doens´t hit the back- or forward-button.

But if he (the user) does, the interval fires multiple times... why?

I save the Interval in a variable and clear this variable so i don´t know why this dont work... but see yourself:

```
        jQuery.fn.extend({
wrGallery: function() {
    return this.each(function() {

        //  config
        var wrClassActive = 'galerie_active';
        var wrTime = 5000;
        //  wrAutomaticDirection gibt an, in welche Richtung 
        //  die Gallerie bei automatischem Wechsel wechseln soll (True = vorwärts/rechts)
        var wrAutomaticDirection = true;

        var wr = jQuery(this);
        var wrGalleryContents = wr.find('.galerie_content');
        var wrGalleryContentsFirst = wr.find('.galerie_content:first-child');
        var wrBtnBack = wr.find('#galerie_backward');
        var wrBtnFor = wr.find('#galerie_forward');
        var wrTimer = 0;
        var wrI = 0;
        var wrOldActiveID = 0;

        var wrInit = function() {
            wrGalleryContents.each(function() {
                wrI++;
                jQuery(this).attr('id', wrI);
                jQuery(this).css({
                    display: 'none',
                    opacity: 0
                })
            })

            wrGalleryContentsFirst.css({
                display: 'block',
                opacity: 1
            })
            wrGalleryContentsFirst.addClass('galerie_active')
            wrStartTimer();
        }

        var wrStartTimer = function() {
            wrTimer = setInterval(function() {
                wrChange(wrAutomaticDirection);
            }, wrTime)
        }

        var wrStoppTimer = function() {
            clearInterval(wrTimer);
            wrTimer = 0;
        }

        var wrBackground = function(wrDirection) {
            wrOldActiveID = wr.find('.' + wrClassActive).attr('id');
            wr.find('.' + wrClassActive).removeClass(wrClassActive);

            if (wrDirection) {
                wrOldActiveID++;
                if (wrOldActiveID <= wrI) {
                    wr.find('#' + wrOldActiveID).addClass(wrClassActive);
                } else {
                    wr.find('#1').addClass(wrClassActive);
                }
            } else {
                wrOldActiveID--;
                if (wrOldActiveID <= wrI) {
                    wr.find('#' + wrOldActiveID).addClass(wrClassActive);
                } else {
                    wr.find('#3').addClass(wrClassActive);
                }
            }
        }

        var wrAnimate = function(wrDirection) {
            wrGalleryContents.stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 500);
            wr.find('.' + wrClassActive).css({
                display: 'block'
            })
            wr.find('.' + wrClassActive).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);

        }

        var wrChange = function(wrDirection) {
            wrBackground(wrDirection);
            wrAnimate(wrDirection);

        }

        wr.on('mouseenter', function() {
            wrStoppTimer();
        });

        wr.on('mouseleave', function() {
            wrStartTimer();
        });

        wrBtnBack.on('click', function() {
            wrStoppTimer();
            wrStartTimer();
            wrChange(false);
        });

        wrBtnFor.on('click', function() {
            wrStoppTimer();
            wrStartTimer();
            wrChange(true);
        });


        wrInit();

    });
}
```

});

**Thanks for reading ;-)**

Comment: this looks like only a portion of the code, can you share the complete code

Comment: `StoppTimer(true);` why passing as parameter a boolean here? And why using this line `Timer = 0;` in StoppTimer()?

Comment: I´ve clean up the code, thats right. 
the other code doens´t work with the interval... dont think that would be useful, to give you the full code... seriously :D

@roasted forget the boolean :D have forgot to delete it...

Comment: @ChristophBrauckmann Anyway, this is not your issue here but clean code is always better ;) But remove Timer = 0 in StoppTimer function too, this is useless

Comment: allright, will host the full code here. give me a moment

Comment: `SatrtTimer()` should always check to see if a timer is already running and either cancel it or don't make a new one.  As the code is now, you could easily get multiple timers going at the same time.

Comment: but to avoid a multiple interval i saving the interval in a variable... Oo

Comment: how can i check for an interval that is running?^^

Comment: @ChristophBrauckmann a setInterval returns only an integer which is ref ID of an interval, not the interval object itself. The global variable is overwritten with the last ref ID. If you then clearInterval using global variable, only the last one is cleared

Comment: @ChristophBrauckmann <<how can i check for an interval that is running?>> You don't have to check for that, using clearInterval(Timer) even Timer not defined is safe. So just put this code before create a new interval in StartTimer()

Comment: Allright, I´ve done it...
Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `wrStoppTimer()` call at the beginning of `wrStartTimer`:

```
    var wrStartTimer = function() {
        wrStoppTimer();
        wrTimer = setInterval(function() {
            wrChange(wrAutomaticDirection);
        }, wrTime)
    };
```

Also in the two `click` functions you have:

```
        wrStoppTimer();
        wrStartTimer();
```

you can remove that `wrStoppTimer()` call since `wrStartTimer()` will call it for you now.

One other thing: if you define functions the way you're doing with `var name = function() { ... }` you should put a semicolon after the closing `}` as in the updated code above.

Comment: Yes, i have found the same solution at this moment your answer comes in!

Thank you ;-)

But i dont understand, why this multiple interval is possible... 
I save the interval in a variable and clear the interval with this variable...

can someone explain this for me? :-P

Comment: There were two places in the code where `wrStartTimer()` appeared by itself: in `wrInit()` and in `wr.on('mouseleave',...)`. It would have to be one of those two. If you're curious which, you could find out by commenting out the `wrStoppTimer()` you added inside `wrStartTimer()`, and confirm that the problem comes back. Then add a `wrStoppTimer()` before one of those two lonely `wrStartTimer()` calls. If that doesn't fix it, add it before the other one. One of the two should fix it and you'll know which it was - my guess is the `mouseleave`. (And then you can put the more robust fix back in.)